# Numba vectorize maxing out all processors

Tags: python, vectorization, numba

Does anyone know if there is a way to configure anaconda such that @vectorize does not take all the processors available in the machine?  For example, if I have an eight core machine, I only want @vectorize to use four cores.

Comment: anaconda is just a python environment. I assume you are using numba's vectorize annotation?

Comment: @marscher, that is correct.  I am using the numba's vectorize annotation.  Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 2):

You can limit the number of threads that `target=parallel` will use by setting the `NUMBA_NUM_THREADS` envvar.  Note that you can't change this after Numba is imported, it gets set when you first start it up.  You can check whether it works by examining the value of `numba.config.NUMBA_DEFAULT_NUM_THREADS`